# MVC partial view containing multiple forms will not update UI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have an MVC application. It has a partial view that renders a number of forms by way of a loop.
These are ajax forms and should update the UI on a submit. The problem is that I can step into the controller and it changes the model correctly but the UI doesn't update.

This is my partial view. You can see a loop that creates a number of ajax forms...

```
@{
    Layout = string.Empty;
}
<div id="divTileHistory">
    @foreach (var t in Model.TileHistory)
    {              
        <article class="tile-prev">
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("RemoveTileFromHistory", "Home", new { controller = "Home" }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "divTileHistory" }, new { }))
            { 
                <div class="tile-prev-inner">
                    <h1>
                        @t.Title</h1>
                    <p>
                        @t.Quote1</p>
                </div>

                <input type="hidden" name="archiveTileId" id="archiveTileId" value="@t.ArchiveTileId" />                   
                <input id="submit_@t.ArchiveTileId" type="submit" value="Delete" class="button primary small radius checkin" />                    
            }
        </article>
    }
</div>
```

The partial view is rendered on the host page like this...

```
  <section class="user-prev-tiles row">
                <h3>
                    Tiles by @Model.User.SafeUserName</h3>
                @Html.Partial("ProfileArchiveTilesPartial", Model)
  </section>
```

And my controller looks like this...

```
[Authorize]
public PartialViewResult RemoveTileFromHistory(string archiveTileId)
{
    UserModelActions u = new UserModelActions((User as CustomPrincipal).Id);
    u.DeleteTileFromHistory(int.Parse(archiveTileId));

    UserModel um = new UserModel((User as CustomPrincipal).Id);
    return PartialView("ProfileArchiveTilesPatial", um);
}
```

There is another partial view that updates correctly on the page so I'm sure I have the right scripts included. My controller get called on the submit of the form correctly as well.

I also think I have the 'target div' id set up correctly.

Does anyone know why this might not be working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the `divTileHistory` div outside the partial in your main view:

```
<section class="user-prev-tiles row">
    <h3>Tiles by @Model.User.SafeUserName</h3>
    <div id="divTileHistory">
        @Html.Partial("ProfileArchiveTilesPartial", Model)
    </div>
</section>
```

Also make sure that the model you are passing to your view in the `RemoveTileFromHistory` is with the correct number of `TileHistory` collection. You could use the `Network` tab of Google Chrome to inspect the exact partial markup returned by your controller action and check if it is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have tried to move the div but that hasn't helped. I have also watched the model that is returned, when looking at it in the Visual Studio debugger it looks correct (is has the expected number in the collection). Any other ideas?

Comment: Does the controller action return correct markup? Did you look at the Network tab in Google Chrome? That's where you can reliably see what's exactly returned from your AJAX request.

Comment: Thanks, you put me on the right path. Chrome showed in an 500 error has happening. There was a typo in the controller. It was returning a view named 'ProfileArchiveTilesPatial' instead of 'ProfileArchiveTilesPartial'. Easy, thanks.